# Override javascript helper function in a library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am importing a library (MyClass) that uses a helper function:

myclass.js

```js
export default class MyClass{
    // ...

    function runSomething(){
        helperFunction()
    }
}

function helperFunction(){
   // do something here
}
```

index.js

```js
import MyClass from 'MyClass'

export default {
    function test(){       
       obj = new MyClass()
       // override helperFunction, but how?
       helperFunction = function(){}

       obj.runSomething()
    }
}
```

How can I override the helper function in myclass.js?

Comment: Not possible unless you can modify `myclass` - the `helperFunction` it references is private to the module and unchangeable from outside of it

Comment: You can write a new class, extending the old one. In the new class, override the `runSomething()` method as you want (i.e: call a modified version of `helperFunction()` - which you should name differently, so you don't temper with how other instances of the initial class work).